# ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, haml

I am facing this runtime error after deploying mysite to VPS. note that in my local machine every thing is working fine.

when I try to access any view via controller route lets say PostsController#index

I got this error

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template posts/index, application/index with {:handlers=>[:builder, :erb], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en]}. Searched in:
"/home//dev..com/releases/20120413023845/app/views"
):
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

I am thinking that haml is the cause of the problem but I am not sure yet.

I added haml gems and bundled my app

```
  gem 'haml'
  gem 'haml-rails'
```

update:

when I changed index.html.haml to index.html.erb and commented the template content it works but it ignored the application.html.haml layout without errors.

i noticed that the application didnot compile my hamls when cap command run

```
RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile

Compiled application.js  (1ms)  (pid 15420)
Compiled application.css  (1ms)  (pid 15420)
Compiled application.js  (1ms)  (pid 15420)
Compiled application.css  (1ms)  (pid 15420)
```

does this mean I have problem with haml converter that is managed by the asset pipeline? how can I tell rails to handle haml in the production environment.

this is my production gems version

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.2.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.3) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.3) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.3) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.3) 
Using mime-types (1.18) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.3) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.3) 
Using activeresource (3.2.3) 
Using highline (1.6.11) 
Using net-ssh (2.3.0) 
Using net-scp (1.0.4) 
Using net-sftp (2.0.5) 
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0) 
Using capistrano (2.11.2) 
Using chunky_png (1.2.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.1) 
Using execjs (1.3.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.6.6) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.3) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using fssm (0.2.9) 
Using sass (3.1.15) 
Using compass (0.12.1) 
Using compass-rails (1.0.1) 
Using haml (3.1.4) 
Using haml-rails (0.3.4) 
Using hpricot (0.8.6) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.11) 
Using bundler (1.1.3) 
Using rails (3.2.3) 
Using sexp_processor (3.1.0) 
Using ruby_parser (2.3.1) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using uglifier (1.2.4)
```

Comment: How are you running the rails app on VPS? webrick? apache? nginx? it might have something to do with how the request is being handled before it reaches the rails routing.

Comment: I am using apache. do you think the problem because of :handlers=>[:builder, :erb] does not include :haml. if yes how can I add haml to handlers list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227945/rails-3-not-loading-haml-handler This looks similar to your problem.

Comment: I tries all the option in the thread and they didnt solve mine!

Comment: I have the same problem with almost ever external template handler. (jbuilder/rabl ...). Non of them make it to the handlers list.

Comment: "/home//dev..com/releases/20120413023845/app/views" is the // a typo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be your

```
gem 'haml'
```

is not in production group (or, is not outside the development group)

Comment: Adding the haml gem to the production group in the Gemfile worked for me. Was getting error on Heroku environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check that gem 'haml-rails' in in :production group too in your Gemfile